# is "it won't be for another ... until" correct?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say:
"it won't be for another 3 months until I leave"
I don't know why it feels correct but it does to me.
But is it actually ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are combining two slightly different expressions.

> I won't be leaving for another three months.
>
> It'll be another three months until I leave.

Comment: haha thanks it's a really funny mistake now that I see it